# Не запускается Qt приложение после использования windeployqt, macdeployqt

Tags: c++, qt

Написал программу на qt, скомпилировал на выпуск, использовал windeployqt --release, а программа запросила еще dll файлы. Я скинул недостающие dll файлы в папку с проектом, потом выдало следующую ошибку. Как исправить? [image]

Comment: "Я скинул недостающие dll файлы в папку с проектом" какие и где вы их взяли?